# Is there a better reference for existence/regularity for parabolic PDEs (and systems) than the book of Ladyzenskaja, Solonnikov, Uralceva?

Tags: reference-request, parabolic-pde

The book of Ladyzenskaja, Solonnikov, Uralceva contains almost everything most people need yet the typesetting and notation is disgusting to the eye. Is there any better text that covers the same type of content, including systems of parabolic equations (hence the book of Liebermann does not count) and Holder regularity etc, and is modern?

Comment: Sometimes we need to be gracious for what we do have, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, but it's been 50 years since that book was released...

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook Oldie but goldie.